# how to break/disect a sprite using anengine box2d?

Tags: box2d, sprite, andengine

I have a sprite that is a stick. My sprite is connected to physics Boxbody(box2d). I want  if i click on the middle of the stick it should be broken from the middle and if i click in the start it should be broken at that point.

Any suggestion or link would be appreciable :)

Comment: I presume it would be a matter of slicing/splitting the polygon used as the box2d body's shape definition, removing the body, then creating new bodies using the result of the polygon slice operation and applying forces based on how the polygon "broke".

Comment: Great George ! ok i understand the physics part. what about the sprite recreation ? like if i slice it in such a way that i is supposed to loo like a parallelogram ! the physics part is ok. how would i create new two sprites that look like paralellogram where as initially it was rectangular !

Comment: I guess there are quite a bit of results for [polygon slicing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=polygon+slicing&aq=f&oq=polygon+slicing&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62.5577&sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly the maths on how to create polys from segments but the way you need to understand it is that you have to destroy the current poly you have and then create two new poly where the old one was, this will simulate the effect of "breaking/cutting" a poly in half.